# Data points disappearing on highcharts redraw in the Angular 6 app

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, highcharts, angular6

I call an API based on list selection and redraw the highcharts scatter chart using the data I get back from the API call. The chart consists of 11 series. I have 600 data points in the charts. The chart draws 600 data points in the initial load, without any issues.

But, the subsequent calls to the API doesn't redraw the 600 data points. I get all the data from the API but the number of data points which is drawn in the chart is inconsistent (it is random and less than 600 data points). The code file is huge I will add only the required code blocks.

```
 private drawHistoryForTools(histories: Map<string, Array<DhtToolHistory>>): void {
        if (!this.globalConfiguration)
            return;    

        histories.forEach((value, key, map) => {
            this.drawToolHistory(value, key);
        });
  }

private drawToolHistory(histories: Array<DhtToolHistory>, chartSeriesId: string) {
        let chartData = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < histories.length; i++) {
            let depth = histories[i].x;
            let density = histories[i].y;

            if (density && depth) {
                chartData.push({
                    timestamp: histories[i].timestamp,
                    x: depth,
                    y: density
                });
            }
        }    
          
        this.chart.get(chartSeriesId).setData(chartData, false);
       
}
```

**On selection, I am calling the following,**

```
 self.drawHistoryForTools(toolsHistory);
 self.chart.redraw();
```

**More Information**
[image]

Ok, I was digging deeper. I got it to work by setting the data to an empty array and then populating it again. The issue here is I should rerender the chart with empty data and update the series with new data. There is a bottleneck since I have 5 series. Is there a better way?

this.chart.get(chartSeriesId).setData([], true);
this.chart.get(chartSeriesId).setData(chartData, false);

Comment: Could you tell me if you are using Highcharts Stock? If so it might be related to the dataGrouping feature. Also, have you tried the official "highcharts-angular" wrapper? 

https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular
https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.series.dataGrouping

Comment: Yes, I am using highstock. Will it fix if I use highcharts? I am not using the wrapper. I cant use the wrapper. I am updating some existing code that was done while ago.

Comment: If the problem is related to the dataGrouping, you could just disable it and check if it will fix the problem. https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.series.dataGrouping.enabled

Comment: @MateuszKornecki thanks I will check and update.

Comment: @MateuszKornecki tried updating the dataGrouping and sorting and no luck. It's a real mystery. could it be data, if the difference between data points are fractions?

Comment: @MateuszKornecki now I have added a slider to filter the data based on a timestamp (something like this example https://jsfiddle.net/bonyfus/zaxeo5cb/127/). Basically show/hide data points when moving the slider. Weirdly, up to about 300-330 data points, it seems correct, but after that, the data passed and the datapoints rendered are different. Check the image above highlight yellow is the data and the other no of datapoints rendered in the chart.

Comment: It is hard to tell you the exact reason without having access to the issue. If it's not related to the `dataGrouping` it might be caused by the `cropThreshold` https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.line.cropThreshold. If not I bet that it is the problem with your data.